# Java String to Date, ParseException

Tags: java, object, date, simpledateformat

I have a string named `DateCompareOld, it has the value "Fri Aug 12 16:08:41 EDT 2011"`. I want to convert this to a date object.

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateType =  new SimpleDateFormat("E M dd H:m:s z yyyy");
 Date convertDate = dateType.parse(DateCompareOld);
```

But everytime I try this, I get a parse exception. I have tried other SimpleDateFormat formatting criteria, but it always fails.

Suggestions?

Comment: For new readers here I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the first half of [the good answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67323750/5772882).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this format:

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
```

Quick test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    System.out.println(df.parse("Fri Aug 12 16:08:41 EDT 2011"));
}

// outputs
Fri Aug 12 15:08:41 CDT 2011
```

Output is in CDT, since that's where I am, but the value is right.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateFormat dateType =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
dateType.setLenient(false);
Date convertDate = dateType.parse(DateCompareOld);
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Another important thing to note is that your string has `English` text and therefore you must use `Locale.ENGLISH` so that you do not get an exception or some wrong result when your code is run on a JVM whose `Locale` is not `English`. Anyway, NEVER use a date-time parsing/formatting type (e.g. [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html),  [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) etc.) without `Locale` because these types are `Locale`-sensitive.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "Fri Aug 12 16:08:41 EDT 2011";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d H:m:s z u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-08-12T16:08:41-04:00[America/New_York]
```

If at all, you need a `java.util.Date` object, you can obtain it as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using the legacy API:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "Fri Aug 12 16:08:41 EDT 2011";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d H:m:s z y", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that the `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Note the String passed to SimpleDateFormat() should be corrected to "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
public class DateTest{
public static void main(String []args){
    String DateCompareOld = "Fri Aug 12 16:08:41 EDT 2011";
    SimpleDateFormat dateType =  new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date convertDate = new Date();
    try{
     convertDate = dateType.parse(DateCompareOld);
    }catch(ParseException pex){
        pex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(convertDate.toString());
  }

}
```