# Java Convert Time to iso_instant

Tags: java, time, date-conversion

I have strings like `Thu Feb 04 21:25:12 CET 2021` and `Sat Oct 03 11:57:00 CEST 2020`
and I need to convert it to `ISO_Instant` time but my code doesn't work.

I hope someone can help me.

My Code:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu");
Instant ist = OffsetDateTime.parse("Thu Feb 04 19:03:27 CET 2021", dtf).toInstant();
```

Comment: Related: (1) [Java String to Date, ParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045931/java-string-to-date-parseexception) (2) [java DateTimeFormatterBuilder fails on testtime \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526234/java-datetimeformatterbuilder-fails-on-testtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date-time string has timezone Id instead of timezone offset and therefore you should parse it into `ZonedDateTime`. Also, [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

        Instant instant = ZonedDateTime.parse("Thu Feb 04 19:03:27 CET 2021", dtf).toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);

        instant = ZonedDateTime.parse("Sat Oct 03 11:57:00 CEST 2020", dtf).toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-02-04T18:03:27Z
2020-10-03T09:57:00Z
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>